# Unwanted vertical scrolling in UICollectionView in iOS 7

Tags: ios, scroll, uicollectionview

In my project I had created a custom layout for `UICollectionView`. In that layout, vertical scrolling is NOT possible, only horizontal scrolling is possible.

If that `UIViewController` is the only thing in the `storyboard`, layout is working perfectly, ie, there is no vertical scrolling, only horizontal scrolling is possible.

But if you add `UINavigationController` to `storyboard`, layout fails in **iOS 7** (tested in simulator and device).  Then vertical scrolling is ENABLED. You can scroll a little amount, may be 20 or 30 points.

But for iOS 6, layout is working perfectly with and without `UINavigationController`.(tested in iPhone).

Please help.

Thanks,

**SOLUTION**

I found solution to this.

In iOS 7, some inset was adding automatically to UICollectionView. So to fix it, add following code to ViewController
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

I found solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18989755/3117930

Hope this is helpful to someone
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

what I can tell it tries to focus on the cell that was closest to the center of the pre-transition view layout. However, if there doesn't happen to be a cell at the center of the view pre-transition then it still tries to center where the cell would be post-transition. This is very clear if you set alwaysBounceVertical/Horizontal to YES, load the view with a single cell and then perform a layout transition.

I was able to get around this by explicitly telling the collection to focus on a specific cell (the first cell visible cell, in this example) after triggering the layout update.

```
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:[self generateNextLayout] animated:YES];

// scroll to the first visible cell
if ( 0 < self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.count ) 
{
    NSIndexPath *firstVisibleIdx = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:firstVisibleIdx atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically animated:YES];
}
```

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: thanks for quick response. I tried as you told. It didn't fixed my issue.

Comment: You welcome. Here are some links kindly check them out may they resolve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234915/how-to-stack-uicollectionview-sections   http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Storyboard-based_Collection_View_Tutorial   http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Overview_of_iOS_7_Collection_View_and_Flow_Layout